# logging learning rate schedule in keras via weights and biases

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, wandb

I am training a keras model and using a custom learning rate scheduler for the optimizer (of type tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule), and i want to log the learning rate change via the weights&biases framework.
i couldn't find how to pass it to the WandbCallback object or log it in any way

Comment: Hey, I am from the W&B team. Can you share your LR scheduler?

Answer (score 7):

Updated based on Martjin's comment!

you can log custom learning rate onto Weights and Biases using a custom Keras callback.

W&B's `WandbCallback` cannot automatically log your custom learning rate. Usually, for such custom logging, if you are using a custom training loop you can use `wandb.log()`. If you are using `model.fit()` custom Keras callback is the way.

For example:

This is my `tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule` based scheduler.

```
class MyLRSchedule(tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):

  def __init__(self, initial_learning_rate):
    self.initial_learning_rate = initial_learning_rate

  def __call__(self, step):
     return self.initial_learning_rate / (step + 1)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=MyLRSchedule(0.001))
```

You can get the current learning rate of the optimizer using `optimizer.learning_rate(step)`. This can be wrapped as a custom Keras callback and use `wandb.log()` with it.

```
class LRLogger(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, optimizer):
      super(LRLogger, self).__init__()
      self.optimizer = optimizer

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
      lr = self.optimizer.learning_rate(self.optimizer.iterations)
      wandb.log({"lr": lr}, commit=False)
```

Note that in the `wandb.log` call I have used `commit=False` argument. This will ensure that every metric is logged at the same time step. More on it [here](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/track/log#stepwise-and-incremental-logging).

Call `model.fit()`.

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
model = some_model()

model.compile(optimizer, 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

wandb.init(entity='wandb-user-id', project='my-project', job_type='train')

_ = model.fit(trainloader,
          epochs=EPOCHS,
          validation_data=testloader,
          callbacks=[WandbCallback(), # using WandbCallback to log default metrics.
                     LRLogger(optimizer)]) # using callback to log learning rate.

wandb.finish()
```

Here's the W&B media panel:

[image]

Comment: WARNING: This is very wrong. The logged LR is false, as the LR schedule is called with the step argument, and not the epoch. Step is the batch number. See @cofri 's answer here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Martjin. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to complete [ayush-thakur answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68911117/17578620). As the scheduler updates the learning rate at each batch/step, and not at each epoch, the logger should retrieve the learning rate at `epoch * steps_per_epoch`, where `steps_per_epoch` is the number of batchs per epoch. This value is stored in [`optimizer.iterations`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#attributes).

Picking up @ayush-thakur code sample and changing the `on_epoch_end` function:

```
class LRLogger(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, optimizer):
        super(LRLogger, self).__init__()
        self.optimizer = optimizer

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
        lr = self.optimizer.learning_rate(self.optimizer.iterations)
        wandb.log({"lr": lr}, commit=False)
```

You can then use this callback in `model.fit` training process.

Note that the code above will return the learning rate of the last batch of each epoch. To get the learning rate of the first batch of each epoch, replace `on_epoch_end` with `on_epoch_begin`.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying the answer even further

```
class LRLogger(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        lr = float(tf.keras.backend.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr))
        wandb.log({'lr': lr}, commit=False)
```